# How to print 10 values per line in C where the values are in decreasing order and using only while loops and if-else-statements?

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I want to write a program where the user can input a number between `1` and `100`. The program will then display that number with all numbers preceding it until `1`. Each line should have 10 numbers only. So basically it should look like:

---

[image]

---

I used this code:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main(void) {
    int num, counter;
    counter = 1;

    printf("Input a number between 1 and 100: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    printf("\n");

    if (num> 1  && num < 100)
        while (num > 0) {
            printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d \n", num, num - 1, num - 2, num - 3, num - 4, num - 5, num - 6, num - 7, num - 8, num - 9);
            num -= 10;
        }
    else
        printf("\nInvalid value. Please enter a different number.");

    getch();
}
```

---

But at the end, it still keeps on showing `0` and negative numbers.

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Hint: you can write part of the line only, and then printing `"\n"` conditionally.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Post text as text.

Comment: `num -= 10` gives in example `num = 1`. The condition `num > 0` is true. You'll print then `1 0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8`

Comment: Your whole approach is awkward. Just print the numbers without `\n` and every 10 numbers printed you print a `\n`.

Comment: `void main(void)` --> `int main(void)` See e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the line

```
while(num>0)
```

num may be 3, which is bigger than zero. However, in your printf statement you print numbers up to num-9 which would be -6.
Try printing one number at a time and checking each time if you have printed your desired 10 numbers / line. You could (for example) use the modulo-operator to calculate the remainder if divided by 10. If that is zero you can start a new line.

Comment: Or use a counter variable, maybe easier.